# I can't find these ICs marked Z20hD, K00 JB, S2UI

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, identification

What are the ICs with the markings in the photos?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the end product these chips are housed in? e.g. CD player, TV, charge controller, etc. Typically, SMD IC markings can only be read with the datasheet, as it tells you the marking scheme.

Comment: This is a small handpiece driller controller board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top one is a [Diodes Inc 74LVC2G04W6-7](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Diodes-Incorporated-74LVC2G04W6-7_C460538.pdf) dual inverter.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Inverters_Diodes-Incorporated-74LVC2G04W6-7_C460538.html))

---

The second one is a [Diodes Inc AH180-WG-7](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0007370613_1-2512869.pdf) Hall-Effect switch.

[image]

[image]

(Source: AliExpress)

---

The third one is likely a [Microne ME6211C33M5G-N](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811131510_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6211C33M5G-N_C82942.pdf) LDO regulator.

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. but why the other components are hard to get in this case?

Comment: @MohamedEhab What other components?

Comment: Thanks, you already find it